# Windows 8 Horizontal Content Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsbin.com/exUmaFU/1/edit

I love Windows 8, among many of the apps, and one of my favorites is the weather app. 
Today I wanted to try making "horizontal page content" as seen on the weather app in the screenshot below.

I was trying to do this using DIV's and haven't any luck. I've tried various methods and whatever I tried using percents this didn't work. I reverted to using em with tables and I got the effect I wanted, but now my problem is getting the div's to have at least 90% width on page width.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how this effect can be accomplished.

**Simplified Code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Win 8 Horizontal Content Experiment</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta content='width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css'>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #000;
}

#contain {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#contain table {
    height: 100%;
}

#contain td {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Separate DIVS Inside Container */
#contain .box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80em;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    color: #700;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="contain">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 1</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 2</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 3</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 4</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 5</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="box">
                        <center><h1>Page 6</h1></center>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    function scrollMenu(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('contain').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('contain').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('contain').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollMenu, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('contain').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollMenu, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('contain').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollMenu);
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Win 8 Weather App]

Comment: ? Your demo is filled with text, nothing else

Comment: Weather forecast for tonite: a bit of *Lorem Ipsum* coming from north-east will bring a *dolor sit amet* of fresh air to your brainz.

Comment: Updated so each section is separated by colors. That way you can see the difference between part 1, from 2, and so on. Instead of just text and divs. This way it's easier to see visually.

Comment: `float:left;` maybe? and remove `display:table-cell;` and you need to set a width too i think

Comment: Already tried. Evidently I can't use percents. I've been able to achieve the effect I wanted using em.

Comment: well made 2 sample where you can use divs instead of the table tags

http://jsbin.com/iRoNEke/10/
http://jsbin.com/iRoNEke/9/

Comment: I updated the question & code. I got the effect I wanted, but now my problem is matching the page width by 90%. When I use percents on this the effect basically goes haywire. I tried using window.innerWidth and height in JQuery, but I still can't get the effect I want. So simple but yet annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use tables. Use `inline-block` divs with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` inside div with `position: relative`, `white-space: nowrap` (this will keep the boxes in one line) and `width:100%` and `height:100%`. Make sure you define `html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%}` in your styles.
I created a jsfiddle with what I think you wanted to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/taW4T/2/

Comment: If you want to make the width 90%, you can, simply set the .box width to 90%, which i did in the jsfiddle. You should stay away from tables because they add a lot of unnecessary markup.